# SQL INSERT function with PHP only

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oop, mysqli

**edit** I changed the code to the suggestion answer, all snippets now updated

currently I am playing around with PHP. Therefore I am trying to build a programm which can execute SQL commands. so, what I am trying is to write some functions which will execute the query. But I came to a point where I coundn't help myself out. My trouble is, for the INSERT INTO command, I want to give an array, containing the Data that shall be inserted but I simply can't figure out how to do this.

Here is what I got and what I think is relevant for this operation

First, the function I **want** to create

```
public function actionInsert($data_values = array())
{
    $db = $this->openDB();
    if ($db) {

        $fields = '';
        $fields_value = '';
        foreach ($data_values as $columnName => $columnValue) {
            if ($fields != '') {
                $fields .= ',';
                $fields_value .= ',';
            }
            $fields .= $columnName;
            $fields_value .= $columnValue;
        }
        $sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO ' . $this->tabelle . ' (' . $fields . ') VALUES (' . $fields_value . ')';
        $result = $db->query($sqlInsert);
        echo $sqlInsert;
        if ($result) {

            echo "success";
        } else {

            echo "failed";
        }

    }
}
```

and this is how I fil the values

```
<?php
require_once 'funktionen.php';

$adresse = new \DB\Adressen();

$adresse->actionInsert(array('nachname'=>'hallo', 'vorname'=>'du'));
```

My result

> INSERT INTO adressen (nachname,vorname) VALUES (hallo,du)failed

What I wish to see

> success

and of course the freshly insertet values in the database

Comment: Please do not create SQL queries by joining strings together. You should always use paramterised queries, otherwise you have a significant security risk from SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you @Dragonthoughts, but currently this will not be public and not combined with HTML or so

Comment: I really think that omitting braces for short loops is a bad habit. But maybe it's just me

Comment: You also haven't clarified how the `$data_values`-array look like, when you're calling `rowToData()` or where you use that class at all. You need to explain how your different code snippets are connected and used.

Comment: Btw, you're saying that `$data_values` is an array but you're trying to concatenate it with strings when you make your query? You're also doing it in each iteration while looping through the `$data_values`. There's a lot of strange things in your code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson $data_values ist not an array but I think it should be, I am pretty sure that the actionInsert() function is completely wrong apart from the DB connection, that is the reason why I am asking.. sry for the confusion

Comment: If `$data_values` _isn't_ an array, then why are you iterating through it? I'm not sure what you're actually asking here. You should start by creating a simple insert query (using prepared statements) and get that working first. Then you can try to improve it one step at the time.

Comment: bc I think it SHOULD be an array, and looping through it ist what I think SHOULD be done, maybe you could show me what you thinkt is the right thing.. I am working with PHP for only 2 weeks and don't know better...

Comment: As I said in my last comment, you should start by doing a simple insert query (using prepared statements). There are examples in the manual (and _many_ tutorials online). Forget your classes etc. for now. Make that work and make sure you understand the fundamentals. _Then_ you can start to improve that code. Take one thing at the time.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson what really annoyes me, is that I already did some prepared statements as exercise and all of them would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to consider when you are working with relational databases without using `PDO`:

- What is the database that you are using.

  It's your decision to choose from `MySQL`, `postgreSQL`, `SQLite` and etc., but different DBs generally have different syntax for inserting and selecting data, as well as other operations. Also, you may need different classes and functions to interact with them.
   That being said, did you checkout the official manual of PHP? For example, [An overview of a PHP application that needs to interact with a MySQL database](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php).
- What is the GOAL you are trying to accomplish?

  It's helpful to construct your SQL first before you are messing around with actual codes. Check if your SQL syntax is correct. If you can run your SQL in your database, then you can try to implement your code next.
- What's the right way to form an SQL query in your code?

  It's okay to mess around in your local development environment, but you should definitely learn how to use prepared statements to prevent possible SQL injection attacks.

  Also learn more about arrays in PHP: [Arrays in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). You can use key-value pairs in a `foreach` loop:

  ```
  foreach ($keyed_array as $key => $value) {
      //use your key and value here
  }
  ```

You don't need to construct your query in the loop itself. You are only using the loop to construct the query fields string and `VALUES` string. Be very careful when you are constructing the `VALUES` list because your fields can have different types, and you should add double quotes around string field values. And YES, you will go through all these troubles when you are doing things "manually". If you are using query parameters or `PDO` or any other advanced driver, it could be much easier.

After that, you can just concatenate the values to form your `SQL` query.

Once you get more familiar with the language itself and the database you are playing with, you'll definitely feel more comfortable. Good luck!

Comment: I guess you are right, seems to me that I wanted to head to fast forward and am still missing the basics, I will get more into SQL querys and prepared statements and then try again!

Comment: @Eileen Good to hear that! Be patient if you come across something that confuses you. Also remember to check out the official manual first if there is any.

Comment: I can not thank you enougth, after checking those prepared statements I was able to create the function I wanted within 30min!

Comment: @Eileen Cheers! Glad to hear that you made it work :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this inside of a class? I assume the tabelle property is set correctly.
That said, you should correct the foreach loop, that's not used correctly:

```
public function actionInsert($data_values) //$data_values should be an array
{
$db = $this->openDB();

if ($db) {

foreach ($data_values as $data){
    // $data_values could be a bidimensional array, like 
    // [
    //   [field1=> value1, field2 => value2, field3 => value3],
    //   [field1=> value4, field2 => value5, field3 => value6],
    //   [field1=> value7, field2 => value8, field3 => value9],
    // ]
    $fields = Array();
    $values = Array();
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
      array_push($fields,$key);
      array_push($values,"'$value'");
    }
    $sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO ' . $this->tabelle . ' (' . join(',',$fields) . ') VALUES (' . join(',',$values) . ')';  
    $result = $db->query($sqlInsert);
    echo $sqlInsert;

    if ($result) {
      echo "success";
    } else {
      echo "failed";
    }
  }
}
```

This is a rather basic approach, in which you cycle through you data and do a query for every row, but it isn't very performant if you have big datasets.
Another approach would be to do everything at once, by mounting the query in the loop and sending it later (note that the starting array is different):

```
public function actionInsert($data_values) //$data_values should be an array
{

$db = $this->openDB();

if ($db) {
$vals = Array();
foreach ($data_values['values'] as $data){

    // $data_values could be an associative array, like 
    // [
    //   fields => ['field1','field2','field3'],
    //   values => [
    //              [value1,value2,value3],
    //              [value4,value5,value6],
    //              [value7,value8,value9]
    //             ]
    // ]

  array_push('('.join(',',"'$data'").')',$vals);
}

$sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO ' . $this->tabelle . ' (' . join(',',$data_values['fields']) . ') VALUES '.join(' , ',$vals);  

$result = $db->query($sqlInsert);
echo $sqlInsert;

if ($result) {
  echo "success";
} else {
  echo "failed";
}
```

}

By the way dragonthought is right, you should do some kind of sanitizing for good practice even if you don't make it public.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Eagle L's answer, I figured a way that finally works. It is diffrent from what I tryed first, but if anyone having similar troubles, I hope this helps him out.

```
 //get the Values you need to insert as required parameters
public function actionInsert($nachname, $vorname, $plz, $wohnort, $strasse)
{
    //database connection
    $db = $this->openDB();
    if ($db) {

        //use a prepared statement
        $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO adressen (nachname, vorname, plz, wohnort, strasse) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");


            //fill the Values
            $insert->bind_param('ssiss', $nachname, $vorname, $plz, $wohnort, $strasse);

            //but only if every Value is defined to avoid NULL fields in the Database
            if ($vorname && $nachname && $plz && $wohnort && $strasse) {
```

**edited**

```
                $inserted = $insert->execute(); //added $inserted

                //this is still clumsy and user unfriendly but serves my needs 
                if ($inserted) {//changed $insert->execute() to $inserted
                    echo 'success';

                } else {

                    echo 'failed' . $inserted->error;
                }
            }

    }

}
```

and the Function call

```
<?php
require_once 'funktionen.php';

$adresse = new \DB\Adressen();

$adresse->actionInsert('valueWillBe$nachname', 'valueWillBe$vorname', 'valueWillBe$plz', 'valueWillBe$wohnort', '$valueWillBe$strasse');
```

Comment: You're actually executing the query twice. Save the result instead: `$inserted = $insert->execute();` and check that variable: `if ($inserted) { ... }`